# Npgsql: Correctly performing a full text search using an expression index

Tags: npgsql

Npgsql docs [suggest](https://github.com/npgsql/doc/blob/main/conceptual/EFCore.PG/mapping/full-text-search.md/#method-2-expression-index) performing a full text search based on an [expression index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-expressional.html) using ToTsVector

```c#
.Where(p => EF.Functions.ToTsVector("english", p.Title + " " + p.Description).Matches("Npgsql"))
```

As I understand expression indexes, they require that the query uses the same expression that was used to create the index, ie `"Name" || ' ' || "Description"`. 
However it seems to me that `p.Title + " " + p.Description` is evaluated before being translated to SQL as ToTsVector takes a plain string

```c#
public static NpgsqlTsVector ToTsVector(this DbFunctions _, string config, string document);
```

Am I wrong or will the index not be utilized? If I'm correct, is there a way to query correctly without using raw SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you may want to look at the other method, i.e. setting up a TsVector column with HasGeneratedTsVectorColumn.

Regardless, `p.Title + " " + p.Description` definitely isn't evaluated before being translated to SQL - that can't happen assuming `p` refers to a database column. If you [turn on SQL logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/simple-logging), you should see the exact SQL being generated by EF Core against your database. To be extra sure that the query uses your expression index, you can use EXPLAIN on that SQL and examine the query plan.

Comment: I'm trying to abstract full text search and other RDBMSs don't use vector columns. I have a method that directly calls yours but it's in a different assembly and I think that might be why LINQ tells me it "could not be translated".

Comment: Which assembly your method is in shouldn't have any impact on the translatability of a LINQ statement... I'd recommend first trying it out in a simple code sample, and then making it more complex from there to suit your purposes. Otherwise you're going to have to share a runnable code sample for any further investigation.